# fetch data then build listview

Tags: dart, flutter

am trying to fetch data and then display it in a listview .. first i will take a hash value and then compare it with the hash i have saved if its the same then i will take the saved json data if not i will call the api ... like this:

```
Future<String> get _localPath async {
final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
return directory.path;
}

Future<File> get _localFile async {
final path = await _localPath;
File f = File('$path/mypollshash.txt');
if (f.existsSync()) {
  print('exists');
  String contents = await f.readAsString();
  content = contents;
  fetchHash();
} else {
  print('not exists');
  fetch();
}
return f;
}

Future checkfileexist() async {
try {
  final file = await _localFile;
  String contents = await file.readAsString();
  content = contents;
} catch (e) {
  //return 'nothing';
}
}

Future<File> writehash(String hash) async {
final file = await _localFile;
return file.writeAsString('$hash', mode: FileMode.write);
}

Future<File> get _localjson async {
final path = await _localPath;
return File('$path/mypolls.json');
}

Future<File> writejson(String json) async {
final file = await _localjson;
return file.writeAsString('$json', mode: FileMode.write);
}

Future readjson() async {
try {
  final file = await _localjson;
  String contents = await file.readAsString();
  content = contents;
  setState(() {
    polls = pollsFromJson(content);
  });
  writejson(pollsToJson(polls));
  writehash(polls.hash);
  print('here');
  //  return contents;
} catch (e) {
  print('there');
  print(e);
  // If we encounter an error, return 0
  //return 'nothing';
}
}

fetch() async {
String data =
    await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/mypolls.json");
setState(() {
  polls = pollsFromJson(data);
});
writejson(pollsToJson(polls));
writehash(polls.hash);
}

fetchHash() async {
String data = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
    .loadString("assets/pollshash.json");
print(content);
final pollshash = pollshashFromJson(data);
if (content == pollshash.hash) {
  print('take from the saved json');
  readjson();
} else {
  print('call api');
  fetch();
}
}
```

and am calling it here:

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
checkfileexist();
}
```

the problem is once the page is launched i will get the red error flutter screen that the length is null .. because the data is not fetched yet .. and then the list will be displayed ..

How i can fetch the data fisrt and then build the list so i will not get the error?

also the functions keeps repeating over and over again since am getting theses messages:

> I/flutter ( 3556): exists
>   I/flutter ( 3556): d1f4bd60f52991d100adafa416f48b52
>   I/flutter ( 3556): take from the saved json
>   I/flutter ( 3556): here
>   I/flutter ( 3556): exists
>   I/flutter ( 3556): d1f4bd60f52991d100adafa416f48b52
>   I/flutter ( 3556): take from the saved json
>   I/flutter ( 3556): here
>   I/flutter ( 3556): exists
>   I/flutter ( 3556): d1f4bd60f52991d100adafa416f48b52
>   I/flutter ( 3556): take from the saved json
>   I/flutter ( 3556): here
>   I/flutter ( 3556): exists
>   I/flutter ( 3556): d1f4bd60f52991d100adafa416f48b52
>   I/flutter ( 3556): take from the saved json
>   I/flutter ( 3556): here
>   I/flutter ( 3556): exists
>   I/flutter ( 3556): d1f4bd60f52991d100adafa416f48b52
>   I/flutter ( 3556): take from the saved json
>   I/flutter ( 3556): here
>   I/flutter ( 3556): exists
>   I/flutter ( 3556): d1f4bd60f52991d100adafa416f48b52
>   I/flutter ( 3556): take from the saved json
>   I/flutter ( 3556): here
>   I/flutter ( 3556): exists
>   I/flutter ( 3556): d1f4bd60f52991d100adafa416f48b52
>   I/flutter ( 3556): take from the saved json
>   I/flutter ( 3556): here
>   I/flutter ( 3556): exists
>   I/flutter ( 3556): d1f4bd60f52991d100adafa416f48b52
>   I/flutter ( 3556): take from the saved json
>   I/flutter ( 3556): here
>   I/flutter ( 3556): exists
>   I/flutter ( 3556): d1f4bd60f52991d100adafa416f48b52
>   I/flutter ( 3556): take from the saved json
>   I/flutter ( 3556): here
>   I/flutter ( 3556): exists
>   I/flutter ( 3556): d1f4bd60f52991d100adafa416f48b52
>   I/flutter ( 3556): take from the saved json
>   I/flutter ( 3556): here
>   I/flutter ( 3556): exists
>   I/flutter ( 3556): d1f4bd60f52991d100adafa416f48b52
>   I/flutter ( 3556): take from the saved json
>   I/flutter ( 3556): here
>   I/flutter ( 3556): exists
>   I/flutter ( 3556): d1f4bd60f52991d100adafa416f48b52
>   I/flutter ( 3556): take from the saved json
>   I/flutter ( 3556): here
>   I/flutter ( 3556): exists
>   I/flutter ( 3556): d1f4bd60f52991d100adafa416f48b52
>   I/flutter ( 3556): take from the saved json
>   I/flutter ( 3556): here
>   I/flutter ( 3556): exists
>   I/flutter ( 3556): d1f4bd60f52991d100adafa416f48b52
>   I/flutter ( 3556): take from the saved json
>   I/flutter ( 3556): here
>   I/flutter ( 3556): exists
>   I/flutter ( 3556): d1f4bd60f52991d100adafa416f48b52
>   I/flutter ( 3556): take from the saved json
>   I/flutter ( 3556): here
>   I/flutter ( 3556): exists
>   I/flutter ( 3556): 
>   I/flutter ( 3556): call api
>   I/flutter ( 3556): exists
>   I/flutter ( 3556): d1f4bd60f52991d100adafa416f48b52
>   I/flutter ( 3556): take from the saved json
>   I/flutter ( 3556): here
>   .....

how can i call it only once? when the page is first launched?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a FutureBuilder

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html
see the sample code, where '_calculation' for you is the source of data.

It needs to be wrapped in a Future.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do it in my case .. am a little confused ..

Comment: It's not clear from your code what is the list you want use... in your initstate you have to initialize the list you want to use in the build as the other answer mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Widget _myBuild() {
  return FutureBuilder(
      future: _fetchData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          // Update UI with data
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          // show error
        }
        // show progress indicator
        CircularProgressIndicator();
      });
}
```

Comment: got this error: I/flutter ( 9112): A build function returned null.
I/flutter ( 9112): The offending widget is: FutureBuilder<dynamic>
I/flutter ( 9112): Build functions must never return null. To return an empty space that causes the building widget to
I/flutter ( 9112): fill available room, return "new Container()". To return an empty space that takes as little room as
I/flutter ( 9112): possible, return "new Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)".

Comment: You can put this in your build method and once the data is fetched then automatically your UI will be updated.

Comment: but this will be calling the methods forever it wont stop .. why?

Comment: Since we are not calling `setState()` from our `FutureBuilder` so there is no loop stuff, it will only gets called once the future is completed that is just one time. If you want to listen for continuous data change then you can use `StreamBuilder` for that case.